# tsql UNION between 2 select statements

Tags: sql

I have 2 complex sql statements but they both have the same column name.
I am trying to do a union between both but the

```
    UNION
```

says Incorrect syntex near UNION.

not sure if there is anything else necessary to make it work.

Comment: since you filtered out any information that could be useful in solving your problem, voting to close. THis is not answerable as is.

Comment: probably need to move your `order by`s above the union...if the columns didn't match you'd only get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax that I usually use for unions is:

```
select *
from 
(
  (<subquery 1>)
  union all
  (<subquery 2>)
) t
```

`UNION ALL` is more efficient than `UNION`, since it doesn't check for an eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Because I always terminate my SQL statements with a semicolon (), I sometimes see this error e.g.

```
SELECT c 
  FROM T1;  <-- forgot to remove the terminator!
UNION
SELECT c 
  FROM T2;
```